# I can not move to checkout page magento 2

Tags: error, addtocart, checkout-page

I click on "add to cart" but can't move to checkout page, only move to this page. **Product** is not going to the **cart**.
[image]

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Comment: What is your **url** do it is present on a live site or into your localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Clean the browser cache or change your browser. I have got this issue. It cause my browser.

Comment: I have tried to clear the cache but the problem is not resolved. Do you have another solution? Last month, I installed a version in chrome and ran on opera is still checkout but now not

Comment: When I get this problem. I have change my browser and use Private Browsing Page.

Comment: Yes, I did the same before, but now I can not checkout anymore T_T

Comment: Try to remove pub/static and run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`